# Mount WebDAV share on Windows programmatically and show login dialog only if required

Tags: networking, authentication, dictionary, webdav

I need to mount WebDAV share programmatically on Windows. I do not know the user credentials, each user has its own login/password. Some servers allow anonymous access.

How do I mount WebDAV and present login dialog only if requested by server?

I need exactly the same behavior as Add Network Location Wizard. Are there any chance to call the same Windows API Add Network Location is using?